# ECC p-128 is not generating 32 byte array signature in c#

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

signature1 value is always 39 byte[] array when i convert to hex, length is greater than 64.
I wanted to generate exact 64 length hex signature value from P-128 ECC Algorithm in c#.

Let me explain below code:

1. Making hash of plain text message which i have to sign
2. Read 128bit PEM key from local folder
3. Pass key and generate signature.

   ```
       public static string GenerateSignature(string message, string privateKeyPath)
       {
               string hashMessage;
               using (SHA256 sha256 = SHA256.Create())
               {
                   byte[] data = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(message));
                   hashMessage = convertByteArrayToHexString(data);
                   Console.WriteLine("Signing message: {0}", message);
                   Console.WriteLine("Hash of the signing message: {0}", hashMessage);
               }
               byte[] hashMessageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hashMessage);
               ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA256withECDSA");
               AsymmetricCipherKeyPair publicKey = getPrivateKeyFromPemFile(privateKeyPath);
               signer.Init(true, publicKey.Private);
               signer.BlockUpdate(hashMessageBytes, 0, hashMessageBytes.Length);
               byte[] signature1 = signer.GenerateSignature();

   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different signature formats, one is the ASN.1 DER format, which is used in your code and is explained [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797). For curve *secp128r1* (*P-128*) the generated signatures have a length between 38 and 40 bytes.

The format you seem to expect is *r | s* (see [here](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/digital-signatures/ecdsa-sign-verify-messages#ecdsa-sign)), which for curve *secp128r1* has a length of 32 bytes.

You can easily convert between the two formats manually.

Newer versions of BouncyCastle for C# also allow the *direct* generation of the signature in the *r | s* format, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62857008), e.g. with `SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA` (instead of `SHA-256withECDSA`).

A few notes:

- According to NIST, a key size of 128 bits is meanwhile too small (instead, at least 224 is recommended for 2019-2030), [here](https://www.keylength.com/en/4/). *secp128r1* was still recommended in [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters V1.0](https://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf) (from 2000), but no longer in [SEC 2: Recommended Elliptic Curve Domain Parameters V2.0](http://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf) (from 2010).
- `SHA-256withECDSA` (`SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA`) hashes the message implicitly (with SHA-256), i.e. the explicit hashing is not necessary and results in a double (redundant) hashing.
- Furthermore, in your explicit hashing, not the actual binary hash is passed to the signer, but the UTF-8 encoded hexadecimal encoded hash.
- *secp128r1* corresponds to a key size (order of the base point) of 128 bits (16 bytes). But with SHA256, you are using a digest that is twice as large (32 bytes). In this case according to NIST FIPS 186-4 the leftmost *n* bits of the hash are used, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18489).

**Edit:**

To concretise what has been said so far: The following code UTF-8 encodes the string `message` and generates an ECDSA signature in *r|s* format (which corresponds to IEEE P1363, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946906/9014097)) based on curve *secp128r1* and digest SHA256:

```
public static string GenerateSignature(string message, string privateKeyPath)
{
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA");
    AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = getPrivateKeyFromPemFile(privateKeyPath); // get secp128r1 key pair
    signer.Init(true, keyPair.Private);
    signer.BlockUpdate(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
    byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();
    return ByteArrayToString(signature); // https://stackoverflow.com/a/311179/9014097
}
```

Note the differences compared to the code you originally posted:

- Since (`Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.`) `ISigner#GenerateSignature()` hashes implicitly, no explicit hashing is performed.
- `SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA` generates the signature *directly* in *r|s* format and exists since v1.8.4 (bccrypto-csharp-1.8.4, released 27th October 2018).

In case of an older BouncyCastle version (where only `SHA-256withECDSA` is available), the signature has to be converted manually from ASN.1 DER to *r|s* format. This is easy, since *r* and *s* can be extracted directly from the ASN.1 DER format, see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797).

If the verification on the client side still fails with the above code, check that the keys, curves and digests on both sides match and the verification process itself.

For completeness:
Of course, also (`Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Signers.`) `ECDsaSigner.GenerateSignature(byte[] msg)` can be used to generate the signature. It is important that this method does not hash implicitly, i.e. here indeed you must hash explicitly. This method returns *r* and *s* as (`Org.BouncyCastle.Math.`) `BigInteger[]` so that both parts can be easily hex encoded with e.g. `toString(16)` and then concatenated to *r|s*.

Comment: Tapaco, I need IEEE P1363 output with single hex string of 64 length, I am getting signature(r,s) and if i joined it converts 64 length hex. Still its not validating at my client place.
please help

Comment: For curve secp128r1 (P-128) the generated signatures have a length between 38 and 40 bytes.
I need exact 32 bytes(using IEEE P1363) then only it will conver to 64 hex

Comment: How did you modify the code to generate the signature in _r|s_ format, did you replace `SHA-256withECDSA` with `SHA-256withPLAIN-ECDSA`? For more complex changes, e.g. if you manually derived the _r|s_ format from the ASN.1 DER format, please edit your answer and add the current code to create the r|s signature (please do not change the already posted code, but add the new code).

Comment: There are other problems in your code, especially points 2 and 3 of my list at the bottom: `ISigner#GenerateSignature()` does the hashing _implicitly_ (which is why the digest name is included in the specifier), so it is not necessary to hash _explicitly_. Thus you could try to replace `hashMessageBytes` in `BlockUpdate` with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message)`.

Comment: The last codes posted differ significantly from the original code. It makes little sense to work with three codes, so I post a possible solution based on the original code, see the Edit section in my answer.